# Reading value from child SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode, sknode

Basic Card object:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Card: SKSpriteNode {
    var cardValue:Int = 0

    init() {
        cardValue = 10
    }
    ...
}
```

Why am I not able to read this value when it's a child of an SKNode?  When debugging with `lldb`, it is showing me the value inside the whole object, but I can't access it:

```
(lldb) p handsOnScreen.children[0]
(BlackJack.Card) $R0 = 0x00007f84937a21a0 {
  SpriteKit.SKSpriteNode = {
    SKNode = {
      UIResponder = {
        NSObject = {
          isa = Blackjack.Card
        }
        _hasAlternateNextResponder = false
        _hasInputAssistantItem = false
      }
      _parent = 0x00007f8493708b60
      _children = nil
      _actions = nil
      _keyedActions = nil
      _keyedSubSprites = nil
      _info = nil
      _attributeValues = nil
      _name = nil
      _userData = nil
      _constraints = nil
      _version = 17096000
      _userInteractionEnabled = false
      _reachConstraints = nil
    }
    _light = nil
    _shouldRepeatTexture = false
  }
  cardValue = 10
  ...
```

After seeing that output, I thought I could just try this:

```
(lldb) p handsOnScreen.children[0].cardValue
error: <EXPR>:1:35: error: value of type 'SKNode' has no member 'cardValue'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must cast your `SKNode` to `Card` in order to access its properties.

```
if let card = handsOnScreen.children[0] as? Card {
  print(card.cardValue)
}
```

I used an `if let` statement instead of force unwrapping (`as!`) to be safe in case the object at `children[0]` would happen to not be a `Card`.

Comment: Nice!  Thank you, that makes sense.  Thank you for the more robust answer, as well (since that child may not be a card).